# How to filter ExtJs GridPanel/ExtJs Store?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to ExtJs. I have a `GridPanel` which is binded with a `data store`. I have a `checkboxgroup`, which containts the possible values of the `GridPanel` row. I want to filter the `GridPanel` with the `checkboxgroup` values.

Here is the code -

```
Store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
url: 'CustomerProfiles/GetDetails',
root: 'rows',
fields:['Name','Id']
});

DetailedResults =
                {
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    autoHeight: true,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    autoScroll: true,
                    border: false,
                    trackMouseOver: false,
                    frame: true,
                    store: Store1,
                    columns: [
                        { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', width: 90 },
                        { header: 'Id', dataIndex: 'Id', width: 50 }
                    ]
                };

Leftpanel = new Ext.Panel({
id: 'Leftpanel',
frame: true,
width: 175,
items: [
        {
            xtype: 'label'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
            columns: 1,
            vertical: true,
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'ALL',
                name: 'chkName',
                inputValue: 'all'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'N1',
                name: 'chkName',
                inputValue: 'N1'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'N2',
                name: 'chkName',
                inputValue: 'N2'
            }, {
                boxLabel: 'N3',
                name: 'chkName',
                inputValue: 'N3'
            }], listeners: {
                change: {
                    fn: function () {
                        Store1.clearFilter();
                        var selectedValue = this.getValue();
                        for (var i = 0; i < selectedValue.length; i++) {
                            Store1.filter('Name', selectedValue[i].inputValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }             
        }            
]});
```

Where I went wrong?

**PS: I am using 3.4 version**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `getValue()` method is a little tricky, the object it returns has variable structure depending on the resultset, that caused the problem in your code. However, the `getChecked()` method is more straightforward, I'll use it in the solution.
Then, we use filterBy as it's more useful in this case.
Here you have the solution (comments inline):

```
change: {
    fn: function () {
        var checkedBoxes = this.getChecked(), //Array of checked checkboxes
            selectedValues = []; //Array of selected values                                       
        for (var i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
            selectedValues.push(checkedBoxes[i].inputValue); //Add each inputValue to the array                                       
        }                                    
        var allSelected = Ext.Array.contains(selectedValues, 'all'); //Whether the 'ALL' option was selected
        Store1.filterBy(function(record){
           //If all was selected or if the name is included in the selectedValues, include the item in the filter
           return allSelected || Ext.Array.contains(selectedValues, record.get('Name'));                                         
        });
    }
}
```

Problem solved. Tested and working :)

**UPDATE**
The above code works on ExtJs >= 4. **For Ext 3.4, this is the code:**

```
change: {
    fn: function () {
        var selectedValues = []; //Array of selected values 
        this.items.each(function(checkbox){
            if(checkbox.checked)
                selectedValues.push(checkbox.inputValue);
        });                                    
        var allSelected = selectedValues.indexOf('all') >= 0; //Whether the 'ALL' option was selected           
        Store1.filterBy(function(record){
           //If all was selected or if the name is included in the selectedValues, include the item in the filter
           return allSelected || selectedValues.indexOf(record.get('Name')) >= 0;                                         
        });
    }
}
```

**OPTIONAL (extra improvements, works only on ExtJs 4.x)**
However, checking your app, I think the following improvements could be done:

- Create the filter checkboxes dynamically depending on the store data
- Sync the ALL checkbox with the rest (i.e. when selecting ALL, select all the other checkboxes)

This is the code with the improvements:

```
var Store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',                
        url: 'CustomerProfiles/GetDetails',
        reader: {                    
            root: 'rows'                    
        }
    },            
    autoLoad: true,                        
    fields: ['Name','Id'],
    listeners: {
            //Each time the store is loaded, we create the checkboxes dynamically, and add the checking logic in each one
        load: function(store, records){
            createCheckboxesFromStore(store);                       
        }
    }
});

var DetailedResults = {
    xtype: 'grid',
    autoHeight: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    border: false,
    trackMouseOver: false,
    frame: true,
    store: Store1,
    columns: [
        { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', width: 90 },
        { header: 'Id', dataIndex: 'Id', width: 50 }
    ]
};

var Leftpanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'Leftpanel',
    frame: true,
    width: 175,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'label'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
            columns: 1,
            vertical: true,

        }            
]});

function createCheckboxesFromStore(store){
    var checkBoxGroup = Leftpanel.down('checkboxgroup');
    checkBoxGroup.removeAll();
    checkBoxGroup.add({
        itemId: 'allCheckbox',
        boxLabel: 'ALL',
        name: 'chkName',
        inputValue: 'all',
        checked: true,
        listeners: {
             change: function (chbx, newValue) {                                        
                 console.log("Changed ALL to ", newValue);
                 if(newValue){  //If ALL is selected, select every checkbox                                   
                     var allCheckboxes = this.up('checkboxgroup').query("checkbox"); //Array of all checkboxes
                     for (var i = 0; i < allCheckboxes.length; i++) {
                         allCheckboxes[i].setValue(true);                                         
                     }
                 }

             }   
        }
    });

    //Create one checkbox per store item
    store.each(function(record){
        checkBoxGroup.add({
            boxLabel: record.get('Id'),
            name: 'chkName',
            inputValue: record.get('Name'),
            checked: true,
            listeners: {
                change: function (chbx, newValue) {
                    console.log("Changed ", chbx.inputValue, " to ", newValue);
                    var checkboxGroup = this.up('checkboxgroup'),
                        checkedBoxes = checkboxGroup.getChecked(), //Array of checked checkboxes
                        selectedValues = []; //Array of selected values                                       

                    //If we uncheck one, also uncheck the ALL checkbox
                    if(!newValue) checkboxGroup.down("#allCheckbox").setValue(false);

                    for (var i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
                        selectedValues.push(checkedBoxes[i].inputValue); //Add each inputValue to the array                                       
                    }                                                                        
                    Store1.filterBy(function(record){
                       //If all was selected or if the name is included in the selectedValues, include the item in the filter
                       return Ext.Array.contains(selectedValues, record.get('Name'));                                         
                    });
                }                                
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is also tested and working :). If you need it, I can pass you a jsfiddle link with the code running (just tell me).

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I am using 3.4 version, seems like `getChecked` is not supported. Im getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getChecked'`

Comment: I have an update. Actually there is another `checkboxgroup` in `items` of `Leftpanel`, say for listing possible Id's. I need to filter the `Gridpanel` with both these `checkboxgroup`

Comment: I added an update for the first code snippet, now it works for 3.4 :). Please take a look

Comment: thats working fine :) 've mentioned about the another `checkboxgroup`, ddn u notice that? same procedure for that `listners` too?

Comment: Thanks :). For an additional checkbox group, the criteria would be the same (add a listener). But maybe it would be easier to use the same checkboxgroup, but adding items with different `name` property or something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44139/discussion-between-sandy-and-edgar-villegas-alvarado)

Comment: thats a different criteria. `Gridpanel` contains a field like date field and the second `checkboxgroup` is for filtering according to date field. checkboxes are like '12 months ago', '6 months ago', 'All time'. Hope you got it.

Comment: Ok, the idea is to combine all criterias in the filterBy method, so you'd finally have something like:

`return ... && record.get('date') < checkboxDate; `

Comment: `{
                xtype: 'checkboxgroup',
                columns: 1,
                vertical: true,
                items: [{
                    boxLabel: 'Past 6 Months',
                    name: '6months',
                    inputValue: '6months'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'Past 12 Months',
                    name: '12months',
                    inputValue: '12months'
                }, {
                    boxLabel: 'All Time',
                    name: 'alltime',
                    inputValue: 'alltime'
                }` and the store field is `adate`

Comment: I tried this in second comboboxgroup
`change: {
fn: function () {
var dateFrom;
var selectedValues = [];
this.items.each(function (checkbox) {
if (checkbox.checked)
selectedValues.push(checkbox.inputValue);
});
if (selectedValues.indexOf('6months') >= 0)
dateFrom = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 6 * 30 * 86400 * 1000);
else if (selectedValues.indexOf('12months') >= 0)
dateFrom = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 6 * 30 * 86400 * 1000);
var allSelected = selectedValues.indexOf('alltime') >= 0;
Store1.filterBy(function (record) {
return Date(record.get('Arrival')) >= dateFrom;
});
}
}`

Comment: this doesn't work for me.. Also this is not practically correct as the store is still the same as orginal(what if I use both `comboboxgroup` at same time?)